# How can I reset the counters from pg_stat_database view?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, statistics

I know I can reset some counters by running:

```
select pg_stat_reset()
```

but some counters like `xact_commit` aren't reset.

How can I do it?

I've tried also:

```
pg_stat_reset_shared('database')
```

but doesn't work.   :-(

Any ideas, please?

I could store the last counters and substract for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, store previous values and substract.
No need to reset anything in Postgres.
In this way meaningful stats can be obtained:

```
(newValue-oldValue)/numberOfSeconds
```